# Why is Math.round() not rounding up when the value is 0.5?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, rounding-error

Currently have a formula which essentially looks like this:

```
Math.round((20.49-14.99)*5);
```

The resulting number is 27.5 and AFAIK, `Math.round()` should round UP if the number is 0.5 and above and round down if it is below. Unless I've misunderstood, I was assuming the result would be rounded up to 28 (as it does in Microsoft Excel, for example), but instead, it rounds down to 27.

At first I assumed it had something to do with my code, but when I console logged it, the result was exactly the same.

Am I missing something and if I have, how would I round-up from 0.5 onwards?

Comment: Well, it's fun when it comes to js math, check the result of `20.49-14.99`, you can jsut type it in console and see the magic

Comment: (20.49-14.99)*5 = 27.499999999 which rounds to 27 because of how IEEE-754 floating values are handled.

Comment: `(20.49-14.99)*5` evaluates to `27.499999999999`, not `27.5`, due to how floating point values are handled.

Comment: @ruby_newbie It's not "because JavaScript", it's because of that's how IEEE-754 floating-point values works.  Other languages will exhibit this same behavior.

Comment: This occurs because `14.99` and `20.49` cannot be represented exactly in binary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I always assumed it just rounded up. 

This totally answers the question for me. 

For anyone that stumbles upon a similar issue, the solution that worked for me is adding `myvariable.toFixed(2)` which rounds up and gives me the desired result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way floating points work, the result of `(20.49-14.99)*5` is actually `27.499999999999993`, which is closer to 27 than 28

Answer (score 0):

`(20.49-14.99)*5` is `27.499999999999993`, so JavaScript will round this to closer value. You should use `Math.ceil` to round above value

Comment: Currently using this formula to display prices and ceil(or floor) is not going to accurately represent the Excel Spreadsheet I recieved. Personally, I have no issues with it rounding accurately (which it is), but apparently, the disparency with the Spreadsheet is an issue.